# DICOM file info to .txt file

Tags: matlab, text, dicom

I have a DICOM file containing a dose distribution from radiation therapy. This dose distribution is needed to calculate various things in MatLab. But somehow, MatLab can't read these particular files, and I have no idea why.

I've tried some programs online, that can actually read them, but I cannot get an export of the 3D matrix containing the dose distribution, which I can then load into MatLab afterwards.

The only thing I have found is a program that gives a txt file with three columns (x position, y position and luminance) for one slice at a time. Ofc, from this I can create what I'm looking for, but it is pretty time consuming to go through 100-1500 slices for each patient to export an individual txt file every time.

So I was wondering if anyone knew a program or something that could do this easily ?

Comment: If it's a binary file [`fread`](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fread.html) should do the trick

Comment: Instead of searching for some other program, you should address your problem with matlab and the DICOM files. What is the problem reading the file? And if everything fails, converting into text is probably the worst choice, for Images you have to use a binary format, otherwise the files are getting to large.

Comment: @Daniel To be honest, it is my colleague, who is using MatLab to do it, that can't get it to work. He just says that he can't read it properly, and gets a null matrix if he tries to  access the dose. It's files like this file: http://1drv.ms/1SMJrDE I have no idea if he is doing something wrong, or it is a weird DICOM.

Comment: can you provide some code and the error message?

Comment: Can you tell us what you have tried, and what result did you get when you say "MatLab can't read these particular files"? MATLAB has relatively decent DICOM support, starting with `dicomread`. There's a whole page of DICOM documentation [here](http://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/accessing-data-in-dicom-files.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can definitely handle this using the built-in MATLAB functions.

To get the DICOM header you will need to use [`dicominfo`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicominfo.html) and then to get the image data that you're trying to get you'll need to use [`dicomread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/dicomread.html).

Using the example image that you provided I was able to load it using the following.

```
info = dicominfo('rtdose.dcm');  % Unnecessary because you can use dicomread directly on the filename
im = dicomread(info);
size(im)

    512   512   1   118
```

As you can see this is a 4D matrix where I'm assuming that the 4th dimension is time. I then looped through the images and found that the most signal occurred between specific time points and I made a gif of these images being displayed in grayscale (frame number in top left).

[image]